# Mapbox.js setStyle differently for each element

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, style, mapbox

I'm using geoJson in a featureLayer so I can use the [setFilter-Function](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.1.6/l-mapbox-featurelayer/#section-featurelayer-setfilter). My question is: How can I use the setStyle-Function and give Elements with different properties different colors?

My Code:

```
var jsonLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer(geoJson).addTo(map);
//Filter for start_year
jsonLayer.setFilter(function(f){return f.properties["start_date"] <=outyear;})
jsonLayer.setStyle(getStyle(this));

function getStyle(feature){return{
stroke: '#555555',
strokewidth: 1,
fillColor: getColor(feature)}};

function getColor(feature){
    if (feature.properties.start_date<="1700"){return "#c78432"};
    else if (feature.properties.start_date>="1800"){return "#F9A63F";}
    else {return "#B8B8B8"};}
```

This obviously does not work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [setStyle()](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.1.6/l-featuregroup/) method to set the style for all features, and use the [eachLayer()](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.1.6/l-layergroup/) method to set the style by feature.

So, something like:

```
var jsonLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer(geoJson).addTo(map);

// set style for all features
jsonLayer.setStyle({stroke: '#555555',
                    strokewidth: 1});

// set style by feature
jsonLayer.eachLayer(function(layer){
    var fillColor = "#B8B8B8"
    if (layer.feature.properties.start_date<="1700"){
      fillColor = "#c78432";
    } else if (layer.feature.properties.start_date>="1800"){
      fillColor = "#F9A63F";
    }
    layer.setStyle({
      fillColor: fillColor
      ... (other Path style options)
    });
});
```

Of course, you don't need the first `jsonLayer.setStyle()` if you already know you are going to set the style at the feature level.

Haven't tested this, but should work.

Comment: Thank you very much!!  That works perfectly. Note: There is a missing = in else if  after fillColor.